# Причина постановки тире в предложениях

Tags: тире, егэ

Подскажите, пожалуйста, причины постановки тире в предложениях.

1. Так, бывало, и хочется подойти к ней, взять её за руку и сказать: "Послушайте, Татьяна Борисовна, вы себе цены не знаете, ведь вы, при всей вашей простоте и неучености,- необыкновенное существо!"
2. Все, что я вам рассказал о житье-бытье моей доброй помещицы, - дело прошедшее; тишина, господствовавшая в её доме, нарушилась навсегда.

Answer (score 2):

(1) *Так, бывало, и хочется подойти к ней, взять её за руку и сказать: "Послушайте, Татьяна Борисовна, вы себе цены не знаете, ведь вы, **при всей вашей простоте и неучености**,— необыкновенное существо!"*

(2) *Все, **что я вам рассказал о житье-бытье моей доброй помещицы,** — дело прошедшее; тишина, господствовавшая в её доме, нарушилась навсегда.*

Это тема постановки тире **между подлежащим и сказуемым**:

*Вы — необыкновенное существо. Все — дело прошедшее.* Подлежащее выражено **местоимениями** (вы, всё). В этом случае интонационное тире **факультативно**, но здесь ставится для **обозначения состава** подлежащего и сказуемого. Запятые **закрывают** обособленный оборот в предложении (1)  и придаточное предложение в предложении (2).